# SQL WHERE timestamp BETWEEN MIDNIGHT AND MIDNIGHT

Tags: sql, date, timestamp, between

For my website I must select all messages sent between midnight (the previous night) and midnight (the next night). Basically, it's a 24 hours range.

I don't know how to do that as I store the date in a timestamp format in my DB.For example, last message was posted on `2013-10-18 11:23:35`.

What I want is all message posted between `2013-10-18 00:00:00` and `2013-10-18 23:59:59`.
Is that possible, if yes, how could I do that ?

Comment: What DB server are you using?

Comment: I'm using MySQL and I tried to use the following query: `SELECT id FROM ff_messages WHERE userid=:userid AND date BETWEEN :minDate AND :maxDate`. Where `minDate` and `maxDate` are generated with my php code `$maxDay = date('Y-m-d' strtotime('+1 day'));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the required time in T-SQL as :

```
-- for previous day mid night  as start time
declare @start_datetime datetime,@end_datetime datetime 
Select @start_datetime = DATEADD(d,0,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE()))
-- for current day mid night as end time
Select @end_datetime = DATEADD(SS,86399,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE()))

select @start_datetime, @end_datetime
```

and then use you column name to check whether it exists between these two values.

Answer (score 0):

To find out what happened between DatetimeA and DatetimeB, the sql keyword between is not your friend.  It generally causes one to miss records.  This construct is better.

```
where YourDateTimeField >= StartDateTime
and YourDateTimeField < JustAfterTheEndDateTime
```

In your case, you can simplify it with

```
where YourDateTimeField >= DateA
and YourDateTimeField < TheDayAfterDateA
```